# Usage of options for symlinks in coreutils

Tags: symlink, coreutils

From coreutils manual

> 2.10 Traversing symlinks
>
> The following options modify how chown and chgrp traverse a hierarchy
>   when the `--recursive` (`-R`) option is also specified. If more than one of the following options is specified, only the final one takes effect. These
>   options specify whether processing a symbolic link to a directory
>   entails operating on just the symbolic link or on all files in the
>   hierarchy rooted at that directory.
>
> **These options are independent of
>   `--dereference` and `--no-dereference` (`-h`), which control whether to modify a symlink or its referent.**
>
> `-H` If `--recursive` (`-R`) is specified and a command line argument is
>   a symbolic link to a directory, traverse it.
>
> `-L` In a recursive traversal, traverse every symbolic link to a
>   directory that is encountered.
>
> `-P` Do not traverse any symbolic links. This is the default if none
>   of `-H`, `-L`, or `-P` is specified.

1. In "These options are independent of
   `--dereference` and `--no-dereference` (`-h`), which control whether to modify a symlink or its referent", what do "these options" and "`--dereference` and `--no-dereference`" do respectively, and how are they different?
2. The descriptions for `-H` and for `-L` seem to say the same thing to me. How are these two options different?

Thanks.

Comment: i think you want http://we-read-man-pages-for-you.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think you don't need to read my posts if you don't like

Comment: By the time I realise it's another one of your "read this man page for me" or "explain the bleeding obvious to me" questions, it's too late - I've already wasted my time reading it.  It wouldn't be so bad if you showed any sign of ever learning from the detailed answers people give you, but you don't.  If you get a good answer, your most common response is to immediately post a trivial and extremely obvious variation of the same question.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. sorry.

Comment: That's the trouble.  you seem to have no capacity to think about or understand anything.  Your first instinct on seeing something you don't understand (which is almost everything, AFAICT) is NOT to think about it or apply previously learned knowledge or experiment and find out, it's to ask someone else to tell you.  Answering you is a waste of time because it never sinks in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-h` flag (aka `--no-dereference`) is a good flag to use.  Let's say we have this setup:

```
$ ln -s /etc/passwd /tmp/foobar
$ sudo chown fred /tmp/foobar
```

Because `--dereference` is the default, this will actually change `/etc/passwd`... which is probably not what you want :-)  The `-h` flag would make it change the symlink ownership instead.  So you should get into the habit of using `-h`, especially if recursively changing ownership. i.e. do `chmod -hR` rather than `chmod -R`.

The `-H` flag only applies to directory symlinks you list on the command line.  The `-L` option applies to all directory symlinks found, including those in subdirectories during a recursive `chown`.

Comment: thanks. 1)  Does "The following options modify how chown and chgrp traverse a hierarchy when the --recursive (-R) option is also specified" mean that -H, -L, and -P are always used together with -R?  2) Does "-P Do not traverse any symbolic links" imply that -P is not used with -R?

Comment: `-P` is the default; symlinks to directories are _not_ followed for recursion.  You need to specify `-H` or `-L` to recurse into them.    This is a perfect case where you can build test trees and experiment.

Comment: (1) Does using -P, -H, or -L  make sense only when -R is used? (2) What do test trees and experiment mean?